# JNI: Catching Init-Time Exceptions

Tags: java, debugging, exception

Okay, I'm all out of ideas on this one. Does anyone have any idea how I can hook into Java's exception pipeline in order to catch (and log to a text file) *all* exceptions that are occurring?

The situation is this: I have a library in a JAR file (A) which in turn depends on a second JAR file (B). A has no main class, as it's simply a class library, which I'm accessing and invoking through the JNI. The problem I'm having is this. When I attempt to initialise the JNI with A loaded, the JNI returns an unspecified error.

I strongly suspect that this error originates from an instantiation of Log4J's logger unit, which is occurring in static code (outside of a method) in B, which I believe is throwing an IOException as a result of permissions problems on the log file. I'm having issues finding out what's going on, however, as the exception (which I suspect is the cause of the problem) is being thrown during the linking stage (when A imports B) and so cannot be caught by a try-catch block. Also, since there is no main method there is no obvious place to put a try-catch block in order to catch this exception.

I would like some way of catching all exceptions that arise in either JAR and dumping them into a text file. I cannot (easily) modify B (I do not have the decompiled JAR). Any ideas?

Here is the C code which invokes the JNI with the specified libraries and options:

```
_DLL_EXPORT PyObject *initVM(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    static char *kwnames[] = {
        "classpath", "initialheap", "maxheap", "maxstack",
        "vmargs", NULL
    };
    char *classpath = NULL;
    char *initialheap = NULL, *maxheap = NULL, *maxstack = NULL;
    char *vmargs = NULL;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "|zzzzz", kwnames,
                                     &classpath,
                                     &initialheap, &maxheap, &maxstack,
                                     &vmargs))
        return NULL;

    if (env->vm)
    {
        PyObject *module_cp = NULL;

        if (initialheap || maxheap || maxstack || vmargs)
        {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,
                            "JVM is already running, options are ineffective");
            return NULL;
        }

        if (classpath == NULL && self != NULL)
        {
            module_cp = PyObject_GetAttrString(self, "CLASSPATH");
            if (module_cp != NULL)
                classpath = PyString_AsString(module_cp);
        }

        if (classpath && classpath[0])
            env->setClassPath(classpath);

        Py_XDECREF(module_cp);

        return getVMEnv(self);
    }
    else
    {
        JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
        JavaVMOption vm_options[32];
        JNIEnv *vm_env;
        JavaVM *vm;
        unsigned int nOptions = 0;
        PyObject *module_cp = NULL;

        vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_4;
        JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&vm_args);

        if (classpath == NULL && self != NULL)
        {
            module_cp = PyObject_GetAttrString(self, "CLASSPATH");
            if (module_cp != NULL)
                classpath = PyString_AsString(module_cp);
        }

#ifdef _jcc_lib
        PyObject *jcc = PyImport_ImportModule("jcc");
        PyObject *cp = PyObject_GetAttrString(jcc, "CLASSPATH");

        if (classpath)
            add_paths("-Djava.class.path=", PyString_AsString(cp), classpath,
                      &vm_options[nOptions++]);
        else
            add_option("-Djava.class.path=", PyString_AsString(cp),
                       &vm_options[nOptions++]);

        Py_DECREF(cp);
        Py_DECREF(jcc);
#else
        if (classpath)
            add_option("-Djava.class.path=", classpath,
                       &vm_options[nOptions++]);
#endif

        Py_XDECREF(module_cp);

        if (initialheap)
            add_option("-Xms", initialheap, &vm_options[nOptions++]);
        if (maxheap)
            add_option("-Xmx", maxheap, &vm_options[nOptions++]);
        if (maxstack)
            add_option("-Xss", maxstack, &vm_options[nOptions++]);

        if (vmargs)
        {
#ifdef _MSC_VER
            char *buf = _strdup(vmargs);
#else
            char *buf = strdup(vmargs);
#endif
            char *sep = ",";
            char *option;

            for (option = strtok(buf, sep); option; option = strtok(NULL, sep))
            {
                if (nOptions < sizeof(vm_options) / sizeof(JavaVMOption))
                    add_option("", option, &vm_options[nOptions++]);
                else
                {
                    free(buf);
                    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nOptions; i++)
                        delete vm_options[i].optionString;
                    PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "Too many options (> %d)",
                                 nOptions);
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
            free(buf);
        }

        //vm_options[nOptions++].optionString = "-verbose:gc";
        //vm_options[nOptions++].optionString = "-Xcheck:jni";

        vm_args.nOptions = nOptions;
        vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;
        vm_args.options = vm_options;
 if (JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **) &vm_env, &vm_args) < 0)
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nOptions; i++)
                delete vm_options[i].optionString;

            PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError,
                         "An error occurred while creating Java VM");
            return NULL;
        }

        env->set_vm(vm, vm_env);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nOptions; i++)
            delete vm_options[i].optionString;

        t_jccenv *jccenv = (t_jccenv *) PY_TYPE(JCCEnv).tp_alloc(&PY_TYPE(JCCEnv), 0);
        jccenv->env = env;

#ifdef _jcc_lib
        registerNatives(vm_env);
#endif

        return (PyObject *) jccenv;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in all of Exception's constructors, and run the code with the debugger. Also, I don't really understand why you are trying to run a jar with jni? JNI is for accessing native libraries not java libraries.

Comment: Show your JNI-side code. If an exception is thrown from Java, you should be able to retrieve it in JNI with `ExceptionOccurred`. Also, have you tried creating a simple Java `main()` that invokes the operation?

Comment: Muel: I'm using JCC to support Python-Java integration as part of a web development project. There's a library I want to use for intelligent reasoning which only exists for Java, but the web app must be written in Python. JCC uses the JNI to instantiate the JVM and then interact with Java objects.

Comment: Parsifal: There's a lot of JNI-side code, as JCC creates wrapper objects for every Java class which is passed to it. The problem relates specifically to exceptions which occur when initialising the JVM with library A. Exceptions thrown after this work just fine. I'll post the JCC function, however, which initialises the JVM and which is throwing the Python exception I'm getting.

Comment: So where does the error occur? Is it from the `JNI_CreateJavaVM` call? That wouldn't normally indicate a problem with any actual Java code, because you don't actually call any Java code (Java is load-on-first-use). However, if that's the case, you need to report the value returned by `JNI_CreateJavaVM`, not simply ignore it; that will give you more information about what's happening. If the error is happening somewhere else, show that code.

Comment: Also: SO uses the "@username" convention to notify a user that a comment is targeted toward him/her. Otherwise, that user never sees the comment. Example @JamesNash.

Comment: @Parsifal - JNI_CreateJavaVM is indeed the operation that's causing the error, specifically I'm getting this error back:

PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "An error occurred while creating Java VM");

I'll mod the code to catch the result returned from JNI_CreateJavaVM and to append it to that error message, but that's going to be a pain as it also means modifying a python install script - the code is generated each time I reinstall the module within which the C code is wrapped.

Comment: @JamesNaish - also be sure to call `JNI_ExceptionOccured` and report the results (in case it is a Java-level exception). That's a good practice in general, as JNI does not have another way to report exceptions to the C code. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp17593

Comment: And you'll find the list of basic error codes in `jni.h`. Be aware there aren't many of them. I'm betting that you're getting either `JNI_EEXIST` (-5) or `JNI_EINVAL` (-6).

Comment: @Parsifal - Well, had a lot of fun hacking that about since there really was no easy to inject my patch into the JCC code, but I did it. The edit shows the patched code, but the highlight is this. The code I'm getting is JNI_ERR (-1). Also had one instance of JNI_ENOMEM but that's only on the first run. JNI_ERR (-1) is the main issue I've had after several runs and server restarts. Any tips?

Comment: @Pasifal - actually, to revise that, there's a pattern. I haven't figured out exactly when I get the error, but it occurs if a page is refreshed too many times, or if I load too quickly after resetting the server. However, when I do get the error it's always JNI_ENOMEM (-4), then if I refresh the page again I subsequently get JNI_ERR (-1) until the error resolves itself. It takes about five or six refreshes of the page to return to the error again.

Comment: @JamesNaish - In the case where you're getting `JNI_ERR`, you should be able to get more information from `JNI_ExceptionOccurred`. The `JNI_ENOMEM` is a little more troubling. When you say "page refreshed," does this mean that you're using a web framework like Django, and spawning a new Python process for every call (and in turn loading the JVM each time)? That's going to be a problem for performance regardless of memory usage, because it takes a significant amount of time for the JVM to start.

Comment: If this is the case, I think I'd abandon calling Java directly from Python, and create a back-end Java service (web service or message-based) that provides access to the library. Although this may present its own problems, especially if the library you're using works with long-lived objects ... you might have to create an abstract service layer that does all of the work in Java. You could potentially write this back-end service in [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) if you don't want to maintain Java code.

Comment: @Parsifal - Yeah. So I'm using the Pyramid web framework which sits on top of MODWSGI. The JVM is called by a process within a Pyramid view. Essentially it's set up as a singleton: I try to use an existing JVM instance, if one exists. I'll abandon my current architecture if I really need to but would prefer to continue with what I have if poss. Thanks for the hint re JNI_ExceptionOccurred. I'll see what that's producing first.

Ultimately, all this is to make use of the semantic web OWL libraries in Java, so the final solution might be to ditch OWL altogether in favour of plain XML.

Comment: Good luck. I think at this point I've gone about as far as I can with suggestions.

Comment: @Parsifal - No worries, thanks for your help. The original question only asked, in any event, for a way to get at the exception which is causing the JNI_CreateJavaVM method to fail (-1). You've answered that question so I think that really clears this issue up. I'll post my revised code as the answer and then close this off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I've got the solution I was after. The solution is an update to the following segment of the code listed in the question:

```
    if (JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **) &vm_env, &vm_args) < 0)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nOptions; i++)
            delete vm_options[i].optionString;

        PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError,
                     "An error occurred while creating Java VM");
        return NULL;
    }
```

The adaptation supports the construction of a more detailed error message which adds two specific pieces of information:

1. The error code (if any) which is returned by the JNI_CreateJavaVM method;
2. The detailed Java exception which occurs in the event that such an error code arises.

The above snippet from the original code was replaced with the following:

```
    vmInitSuccess = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **) &vm_env, &vm_args);
    if (vmInitSuccess < 0)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nOptions; i++)
            delete vm_options[i].optionString;

        //Set up basic error message
        sprintf(strVMInitSuccess, "%d", vmInitSuccess);
        strcpy(strVMError, "An error occurred while creating Java VM (No Exception): ");
        strcat(strVMError, strVMInitSuccess);

        //Get exception if there is one
        if((exc = vm_env->ExceptionOccurred()))
        {
            //Clear the exception since we have it now
            vm_env->ExceptionClear();
            //Get the getMessage() method
            if ((java_class = vm_env->FindClass ("java/lang/Throwable")))
            {
                if ((method = vm_env->GetMethodID(java_class, "getMessage", "()Ljava/lang/String;")))
                {
                    int size;
                    strExc = static_cast<jstring>(vm_env->CallObjectMethod(exc, method)); 
                    charExc = vm_env->GetStringUTFChars(strExc, NULL);
                    size = sizeof(strVMError) + sizeof(charExc);
                    char strVMException[size];
                    strcpy(strVMException, "An error occurred while creating Java VM (Exception): ");
                    strcat(strVMException, charExc);
                    PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, strVMException);
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
        }
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, strVMError);
        return NULL;
    }
```

Thanks to @Parsifal for help with this solution.